# Two ways to represent 0 with bits

Tags: bit

Let's say we want to represent a signed number with 5 bits where the first bit is used for the sign (+ or -) of the number. Then the zero can be represented by two bit representations (10000 and 00000).

How is this problem solved?

Comment: What problem?  You haven't stated one.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think the problem is that we can get +0 and -0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. There are always two bit in binary `1` or `0`

And then there could be any number of bits for example `1bit` to `64bit`

If the question is 5-bit string then it should be `XXXXX` where `X` can be any bit(1 or 0)

**First bit**(sign bit) we can have either +0 and -0. (Thanks @machinery)

So if it is positive, we put 0 at first position and if it is negative, we put `1` at first position.

**Four Bits**

Now, we got our first bit, we are left with another 4-bits `0XXXX` or `1XXXX` as the question asked for 0,

the rest bit will be zero.

therefore the answer is `00000` or `10000`

Look how to convert decimal to binary and binary to decimal.